# How to code survival data so that sarting survival is below 1

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier, ggplot2

I am analysing the time to the end of rehabilitation; however, not all patients receive rehabilitation. Therefore, for making Kaplan-Meier curves for the whole study population (including non-receivers), these curves should start below survival 1. For example, if only 70% of patients received rehabilitation, the y-axis start value should be 0.7. How should I code my time and status variables to make it work? Would it also be possible to make it so that all survival tables take into account the non-receivers?

The following graph isn't ideal, as it shows the event happened for 30% of patients on day 0. This isn't true as they received no rehabilitation.

**Generated data of 10 patients and KM curves**

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  time = c(0, 0, 0, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 100, 100),
  status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)

ggsurvplot(fit, data = df)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear that is a good way to describe your data. What you have is really a 2-stage model: the probability that someone receives rehabilitation, then the distribution of the durations of rehabilitation given that rehabilitation is received. Trying to include the non-rehabilitation patients in the same cohort with those who received rehabilitation in a single Kaplan-Meier curve would tend to be misleading, and it would lead to problems with estimating standard errors around the survival curve.

Comment: I don't believe this is a coding problem, but more something of a modelling problem. The inclusion of the people that didn't receive rehabilitation into the analysis (with a time t=0) is wrong, because this is interpreted as those patients having received rehabilitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't.

As @SextusEmpiricus said in a comment, "The inclusion of the people that didn't receive rehabilitation into the analysis (with a time t=0) is wrong, because this is interpreted as those patients having received rehabilitation."

The best way to show a "survival" curve for duration of rehabilitation is to limit the curve to those who actually received rehabilitation and state that clearly in your report. Also report the fraction of those in the study who received rehabilitation. That way the reader won't be misled.